# WebView String customisation

Tags: iphone, json, ios6, uiwebview

In my application I am using a Web Service via **JSON**, While retrieving it contains some URL links like :

```
   Enfim, aqui vai a review![youtube]http:\/\/youtu.be\/HFn_IRLEAOA<\/a>[\/youtube]
```

I want to show that particular you tube link as :

```
  "Please click here to see"
```

Since I used the code to remove That you as following:

```
   NSString *replac1=[replac stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[youtube]" withString:@""];
   NSString *replac2=[replac1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[/youtube]" withString:@""];
   NSString *replac3=[replac2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[youtube ]" withString:@""];
```

How to add that **"Please click here to see"** instead of that link value? Please help me to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you out:

```
 NSString *html = @"<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pii4G8FkCA4/\">Please click here to see</a>";
[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```